# Calcular Fatorial Array usando Thread's

Tags: c, thread

Estou com problemas no seguinte exercício

> Escreva um programa que, dado um vector com os primeiros 5 números
>   primos, lance 5 threads. Cada um deles vai calcular o valor do
>   factorial de uma das posições do vector e substitui valor dessa
>   posição com o valor calculado. O thread principal espera que todos os
>   threads terminem, imprime o vector e termina também.

Tenho a seguinte resolução

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NTHREADS 5

void *Fatorial(int *array)
{
    printf("***Entrei na função fatorial***\n");
    int fat = 0, n = 0;
    for(fat = 1; n > 1; n = n - 1)
    {
        array[n] = array[n] * n;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    printf("Início da função\n");
    int *array[5] = {2,3,5,7,11};
    int i = 0,rc = 0;
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    printf("Antes do FOR\n");
    for(i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++)
    {
        rc = array[i];
        rc = pthread_create(&tid,&attr,Fatorial,NULL);
        if (rc) 
        {              
            printf("ERROR - return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
        rc = pthread_join(tid, NULL);
        if (rc) 
        {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    printf("Array[] = ");
    for(i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",array[i]);
    }
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Um dos meus problemas está em como fazer com que o array seja calculado na thread auxiliar (que tem como objetivo calcular o fatorial de uma posição do array). Testanto com os print's consigo perceber que o programa entra 5 vezes na thread auxiliar por isso acho que estou num caminho correto. Falta-me perceber como mexer no array propriamente dito.

Answer (score 1):

Como cada uma das *threads* irá alterar uma posição diferente do vetor, ele pode ser declarado como global, e a posição para o cálculo do fatorial, ser informada como parâmetro da *thread*.

Abaixo, segue o código comentado (com mais algumas alterações):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NTHREADS 5

// declara o array como global
// como cada thread irá escrever em uma posição diferente
// não precisa de lock
int array[5] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };

// informa a posição do array para o cálculo
void *Fatorial(void *pos)
{
    int res = 1, fat;
    int *posicao = (int *)pos; // obtém o parâmetro da posição
    printf("***Entrei na funcao fatorial %d***\n", *posicao);
    // calcula o fatorial
    for(fat = array[*posicao]; fat > 1; fat--)
    {
         res *= fat;
    }
    // armazena de volta no array
    array[*posicao] = res;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
  printf("Inicio da funcao\n");
  int i = 0,rc = 0, pos[NTHREADS]; // Um parâmetro para cada thread
  pthread_t tid[NTHREADS]; // Uma posição para cada thread
  pthread_attr_t attr;

  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
  printf("Antes do FOR\n");

  // Primeiro cria as threads...
  for(i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++)
  {
    // cria a thread e informa a posição para cálculo
    // como parâmetro
    pos[i] = i;
    rc = pthread_create(&tid[i], &attr, &Fatorial, (void *)&pos[i]);
    if (rc)
    {
      printf("ERROR - return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
      exit(-1);
    }
  }

  // ...depois, aguarda a execução (join)
  for(i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++)
  {
    rc = pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    if (rc)
    {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
    }
  }
  printf("Array[] = ");
  for(i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ",array[i]);
  }
  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

---

Saída após a execução:

```
Inicio da funcao
Antes do FOR
***Entrei na funcao fatorial 0***
***Entrei na funcao fatorial 1***
***Entrei na funcao fatorial 2***
***Entrei na funcao fatorial 3***
***Entrei na funcao fatorial 4***
Array[] = 2 6 120 5040 39916800
```